# Python: search in file with multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas, criteria, multiple-columns

I have a text file with multiple column like this:

```
1000 1 2 3
1000 1.5 2.5 3.1
2000 4 5 6
3000 7 8 9
```

I would like to create a python script in which I enter a series of 3 number, search the closest number in the first 3 column and return corresponding value of the last column.
For example if I enter `1200 1 2` it should return `3`.

UPDATE: Is it possible to have a linear interpolation between data that have the same value for the second and third row?
For example my data is:
1000 100 2 0.1
1200 100 2 0.2
1000 80  3 0.4
And my input is '1100 100 2', it should return 0.15.

Comment: Hey it would be better if you add some code that you've tried

Comment: At the moment I have no idea how to start.

Comment: You can read this into a pandas df by doing `df = pd.read_fwf(path_to_txt_file)` however you've not defined the criteria for closest, for example you could get only 1 or 2 exact matches but the remaining values are not that close or you could have all 3 have close but no exact matches, is there a weighting being applied here?

Comment: You really need to give this a better try and come back with any problems you've encountered, at the moment this is way too broad and like a 'gimme the code' type question which are disliked on SO. My suggestions are look at loading this into a pandas df, then look at `np.searchsorted` or other search functions and come back when you get stuck

Comment: Let me explain better. The closest value should be looked for each column. So I if enter '1200 1 2', it should take the first entered number (1200) and look for the closest in the first column in this case 1000. Then it should take the second number (1) and look for the closest in the second column but only the rows that meet the upper condition. Same for the third entered number, so at the end it should return the corrispondent value of the last column that meets these condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. open the file,

   ```
   values = []
   with open("myfile.txt") as inf:
   ```
2. read each line,

   ```
       for line in inf:
   ```
3. convert it into numbers,

   ```
           values.append([float(s) for s in line.split()])
   ```
4. define what you mean by "closest". Manhattan distance? Least squares?

   ```
   def make_manhattan_dist_fn(from):
       def distance_fn(pt):
           return sum(abs(b-a) for a,b in zip(from, pt))
       return distance_fn

   my_dist_fn = make_manhattan_dist_fn([1200, 1, 2])
   ```

   **Edit:** based on your comment, you want

   ```
   def make_tuple_dist_fn(from):
       def distance_fn(pt):
           return tuple(abs(b - a) for a,b in zip(from, pt))
       return distance_fn

   my_dist_fn = make_tuple_dist_fn([1200, 1, 2])
   ```
5. find the closest value,

   ```
   print(min(values, key = my_dist_fn)[-1])
   ```

   which results in

   ```
   3.0
   ```

Comment: Is it possible to have a linear interpolation between data that have the same value for the second and third row?
For example my data is:
1000 100 2 0.1
1200 100 2 0.2
1000 80  3 0.4
And my input is '1100 100 2', it should return 0.15.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that?

```
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

input_data = [1100, 100, 4]
values = []

with open("prova.txt") as lista:

for line in lista:
    if line.find('RPM') == -1:
       values.append([float(s) for s in line.split()])

restricted = []
for i in range(len(values)):
    if values[i][2] == input_data[2]:
        restricted.append([values[i][0], values[i][1], values[i][3]])

points = []
valori = []

for i in range(len(restricted)):
    points.append( [restricted[i][0],restricted[i][1]] )
    valori.append( restricted[i][2] )


grid_x = input_data[0]
grid_y = input_data[1]

grid_z1 = griddata(points, valori, (grid_x, grid_y), method='linear')
```

"prova.txt" is:
1200 100 4 0.1
1150 100 4 0.1
1050 100 4 0.2
1000 100 4 0.2
1200 90 4 0.1
1150 90 4 0.1
1050 90 4 0.2
1000 90 4 0.2
1100 100 2 0.3